# count number of member's class and show in grids

Tags: sql, ms-access, vb6

I have 3 tables:

`member` table :

```
|--------|---------------------|------------------|
|   id   |      f_name         |     l_name       |
|--------|---------------------|------------------|
|   1    |      matt           |        jim       |
|   2    |     david           |       joyce      |
|--------|---------------------|------------------|
```

`mentor` table :

```
|--------|---------------------|---------------|
|   id   |        fname        |      lname    |
|--------|---------------------|---------------|
|   1    |         mack        |       pet     |
|   2    |         larry       |       oley    |
|   3    |         roza        |       masti   |
|--------|---------------------|---------------|
```

`class` table :

```
|--------|-----------|----------|
|   id   |  classes  | Capacity |
|--------|-----------|----------|
|   1    |  Math     |  50      |
|   2    | chemistry |  40      |
|   3    |  Physics  |  60      |
|--------|-----------|----------|
```

I use this sql code to data in grids :

```
select mentor.id,mentor.fname + ' ' + mentor.lname, class.classes, class.capacity, from mentor, class where mentor.id = class.id
```

now i want to show data in grid like this to calculate number of member of class

```
|--------|--------|----------|----------|--------------------|
|mentorid| mentor | classes  | Capacity |num of member class |
|--------|--------|----------|----------|--------------------|
|   1    |  mack  | Math     |  50      |    10              |
|   2    |  larry |chemistry |  40      |    12              |
|   3    |   roza |Physics   |  60      |     7              |
|--------|--------|----------|----------|--------------------|
```

The numbers 10, 12 and 7 are obtained from the following query : `Select count(*) as num of member class from member where class = "Math"`. but i can't use this sub query in above query to get one result

The problem is how to calculate the number of class members and display it in the grid along with other information?

It should be noted that access is used as a database

Comment: besides that the query has a fault, how do you get 10 as number

Comment: The numbers 10, 12 and 7 are obtained from the following query : Select count(*) as num of member class from member where class = "Math". but i can't use this sub query in above query to get one result

Comment: please add new information in the question not in comments

Comment: so your member table as more columns?

Comment: the solution is simple make a subquery that Select class,count(*) as num of member class from member GROUP BY class` and join it to your existing query

Comment: yes, I get the number of member in each class through this query. But there is a problem of merging these two queries in one query, which can be seen in one grid. 1:  Select count(*) as num of member class from member where class = "Math" and 2 : select mentor.id,mentor.fname + ' ' + mentor.lname, class.class, class.capacity, from mentor, class where mentor.id = class.id

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not know the order of the queries and their combination. Can you change the same query in a practical way?

Answer (score 1):

As i said you need to join a subquery, with the wanted data, and use always JOINS

```
select 
    mentor.id
    ,mentor.fname + ' ' + mentor.lname
   , class.class
   , class.capacity
   , num_mem.[num of member class]
from mentor INNER JOIN class ON mentor.id = class.id
INNER JOIN (Select class,count(*) as [num of member class] from member GROUP BY class) num_mem ON class.class = num_mem.class
```

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work properly. The [num of member class] column is not in the class table and must be filled in based on the subquery .num_mem.[num of member class] What does it do?

Comment: that is the column created in the subquery as alias for the count(*). when you query `Select count(*) as num of member class from member where class = "Math"`works this should yield the right result. if not, you didn't provide the correct information

Comment: I got it , Do I have to use it exactly the same way in my query? num_mem.[num of member class]

Comment: when I use `code INNER JOIN (Select class,count(*) as [num of member class] from member GROUP BY class) num_mem ON class.class = num_mem.class ` There are problems Syntax Error but separately they work properly

Comment: The problem is still unresolved. I put the database on the sqlfiddle site to test you, please take a look and run query. [link] Demo on SQLFiddle (http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/0102ca/1)

Comment: as i said you need to adjust the columns to your real database see https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4836188adaa71ec5c06126bd54c35a4f

Comment: Thank you very very much . But again the syntax error gives an error. I will copy and execute your code exactly.Is it possible that your code will not run in Access?
If yes, can you change the code to run in Access?

Comment: the code runs also in access it supports joins and subqueries see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13567772/is-it-possible-to-use-subquery-in-join-condition-in-access  which error do you get exactly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245558/discussion-between-user334681-and-nbk).